# How to attach a file in HTML?

Tags: php, html

I have an assignment wherein I'll make a website that will enable the user to attach file and save it to the database. I'm doing some research and found out that I'll need to use PHP and MySQL/SQL for my database. The bad thing here is that I don't know how to use PHP.

Can someone help me in coding to attach a file from the documents of the user and will save it to the database?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Attach file</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table width="450px">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="attach_file"><b>Attachment *</b></label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="submit" value="Attach File">
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="attach_file">No file selected</label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="app_name"><b>Application Name *</b></label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input  type="text" name="app_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="desc"><b>Description </b></label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <textarea  name="desc" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center">
            <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">   
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: No one's going to write you a file upload system for short of a few hundred USD.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since this is an assignment I'll only point you in the direction of the information that you need.

First of all, you need to have the

```
<input type='file' name='upload'>
```

on your page.

Next the php has several pages dedicated to handling file uploads: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Good luck with your assignment.

Comment: +1 For pushing him in the right direction and not doing his assignment for him.